Alternative script of the .setRequireLogin that changing the collecting email on google form
I was running a google app script to create Google Forms. However, starting last month, the .setRequireLogin method suddenly stopped working, and I can no longer change the "collect email addresses" setting from "verified" using the script.
If you know of a script that can change the "collect email addresses" setting from "responder input" to "verified", please let me know."
【Sample code】
    function utecy(){
    let form_name="test_form";
    let Form = FormApp.create(form_name).setTitle(form_name);
    
    Form
    //col mail・limit_org・one_resp
    .setCollectEmail(true)
    .setRequireLogin(true) //<this is the method
    .setConfirmationMessage("thank you")
    .setLimitOneResponsePerUser(true);
    }

Access to the test_form and open the settings, check the toggle "Collect email addresses" will be set as "responder input".
I want that it set as "verified" when generated a forms to get email address automatically.

Apps Script’s setRequireLogin(requireLogin) deprecated
According to Google’s documentation setRequireLogin() is actually deprecated and is not advised to be used anymore. However, I tested your code as is(still with the said method) and the script printed an error but still generated a new Form but to my surprise it can be accessed without logging in then I removed the setRequireLogin method and the form then required a login. Another relevant thing that I noticed and I believe this is where your situation falls into, Workspace account and a regular Gmail account receive different email fields. See images below.
Gmail Account

Workspace Account

Bottom line, using just .setCollectEmail(true) will allow you to achieve the goal of collecting email and requiring respondents to login before submitting a response, however, the field will vary from the type of account that the creator of the Form used.
References: Class Forms's deprecated methods

Thank you for your very helpful comments.
However, in my case, for both gmail and workspace accounts, the 'Collect email addresses' setting is responder input, which does not allow automatic entry, but shows a text area for the user to enter manually.

both gmail and workspace accounts are these account you are referring respondent or the creator of the Form? in my experimentation, this differs on the account the created the form(the account that executed the script.)

Try setLimitOneResponsePerUser(true). This forces login, but I don't think you can get the verified email address.
